# Rails creating a thumbnail gallery in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, thumbnails, gallery

I currently have an Array that contains some URL's to images.

`@images = [ "http://site/images/01.jpg", "http://site/images/02.jpg" ]`

**Total 18 images**

I would like to take this array and create a thumbnail gallery where **the gallery is 3 columns across in my view**. The HTML out put would be

`<table>

<tr>

   <td><img src="http://site/images/01.jpg"></td>

   <td><img src="http://site/images/02.jpg"></td>

   <td><img src="http://site/images/03.jpg"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

   <td><img src="http://site/images/04.jpg"></td>

   <td><img src="http://site/images/05.jpg"></td>

   <td><img src="http://site/images/06.jpg"></td>

</tr>

</table>`

My **current implementation** gets me a one column table

`<table>`
`<tr>`
`<% @images.each do | image | %>`
`<td><%= image_tag(image)%></td><br>`
`<% end %>`
`</tr>`
`</table>`

In the future I might want it to be 6 columns instead of 3 columns.
I'm looking for a way to do this in a clean and flexible way.

I was looking at the **Ruby documentation** and I saw this
**Class Range (rng.step method)**
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html

Not sure if this Range class **step method** can solve the problem but the example it provides is interesting.

Any thoughts, I'm still learning and maybe I'm over thinking this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `each_slice()`

```
<table>
  <% @images.each_slice(3) do |images| %>
    <tr>
      <% images.each do |image| %>
        <td><%= image_tag(image) %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested. You need to use `each_with_index` and the modulus `%` operator.

```
<% @images.each_with_index | image, index | %>
   <% unless index % column_count == 0 %>
         <td><%= image_tag(image)%></td>
   <% else %>
         <td><%= image_tag(image) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: My instance variable `@images` is an Array not a Hash. This solution won't work, but thanks for the tip on the modulus `%` operator

Comment: Of course it will works for you. Only error here is strange `map`. First line should be like this: `<% @images.each_with_index | image, index | %>`

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly. I didn't know each_slice existed!

Comment: as do I really :) I used to use each_with_index not long ago

Comment: Thanks for the tips the `each_slice()` is exactly what I need